# Is there en R function to perform an mixt ANOVA with 2 intra-subjetcs factor and one within subject factor?

Tags: r

I succeed in performing a mix ANOVA with a design with one intra subject variable and one within subjects factor

```
library(ez)
ezStats(data = EVALVFB1, dv = Confidence, wid = ID, between = Protocol, within = Time)
```

It works well!
But when i want to use with 2 intra subjects factors and one within subject factors, i don't succeed.
Can you help?...Thanks a lot

here is the dput(data) if you have time to help me....

> dput(FOCUS_G3)
>   structure(list(ID = c(132, 132, 133, 133, 134, 134, 135, 135, 
>   136, 136, 137, 137, 138, 138, 139, 139, 140, 140, 141, 141, 142, 
>   142, 143, 143, 144, 144, 145, 145, 146, 146, 147, 147, 148, 148, 
>   149, 149, 150, 150, 151, 151, 152, 152, 153, 153, 154, 154, 155, 
>   155, 156, 156, 157, 157, 158, 158, 159, 159, 160, 160, 161, 161, 
>   162, 162, 163, 163, 164, 164, 165, 165, 166, 166, 167, 167, 168, 
>   168, 169, 169, 170, 170, 171, 171, 172, 172, 173, 173, 174, 174, 
>   175, 175, 176, 176, 177, 177, 178, 178, 179, 179, 180, 180, 181, 
>   181, 182, 182, 183, 183, 184, 184, 185, 185, 186, 186, 187, 187, 
>   188, 188, 189, 189, 190, 190, 191, 191, 192, 192), Time = c("T0", 
>   "T1", "T0", "T1", "T0", "T1", "T0", "T1", "T0", "T1", "T0", "T1", 
>   "T0", "T1", "T0", "T1", "T0", "T1", "T0", "T1", "T0", "T1", "T0", 
>   "T1", "T0", "T1", "T0", "T1", "T0", "T1", "T0", "T1", "T0", "T1", 
>   "T0", "T1", "T0", "T1", "T0", "T1", "T0", "T1", "T0", "T1", "T0", 
>   "T1", "T0", "T1", "T0", "T1", "T0", "T1", "T0", "T1", "T0", "T1", 
>   "T0", "T1", "T0", "T1", "T0", "T1", "T0", "T1", "T0", "T1", "T0", 
>   "T1", "T0", "T1", "T0", "T1", "T0", "T1", "T0", "T1", "T0", "T1", 
>   "T0", "T1", "T0", "T1", "T0", "T1", "T0", "T1", "T0", "T1", "T0", 
>   "T1", "T0", "T1", "T0", "T1", "T0", "T1", "T0", "T1", "T0", "T1", 
>   "T0", "T1", "T0", "T1", "T0", "T1", "T0", "T1", "T0", "T1", "T0", 
>   "T1", "T0", "T1", "T0", "T1", "T0", "T1", "T0", "T1", "T0", "T1"
>   ), Protocol = c(3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
>   3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
>   3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
>   3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
>   3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
>   3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
>   3, 3), Sex = c(2, 2, 2, 2, NA, NA, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 
>   1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, NA, NA, 2, 2, 1, 
>   1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 
>   1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
>   1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, NA, 
>   NA, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
>   2, 1, 1, 1, 1), Level = c(2, 2, 2, 2, NA, NA, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
>   2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, NA, 
>   NA, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
>   2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
>   2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
>   3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
>   3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3), Digital_Habit = c(2, 2, 4, 4, NA, NA, 
>   2, 2, 4, 4, 2, 2, 4, 4, 2, 2, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 1, 
>   1, 4, 4, NA, NA, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 
>   2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 2, 2, 
>   2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 
>   3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 1, 1, 4, 4, 3, 3, 4, 4, 
>   4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 1, 1, 3, 3), Perceived_Competence_APSA = c(3, 
>   3, 4, 4, NA, NA, 2, 2, 2, 2, 4, 4, 3, 3, 2, 2, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 
>   3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 4, 4, 3, 3, NA, NA, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 
>   3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 4, 4, 3, 3, 1, 1, 4, 4, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1, 4, 4, 
>   3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 1, 1, 3, 3, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 
>   3, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 
>   3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 3, 3, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3), Somatic_Anxiety = c(2.166666667, 
>   1.333333333, 2.166666667, 3, 2.166666667, 2.5, 2.5, 2.333333333, 
>   2.6, 3.5, 1.166666667, 1.166666667, 1.333333333, NA, 1.166666667, 
>   1, 1.833333333, 1.666666667, 1.833333333, 1.333333333, 1.333333333, 
>   3.333333333, 1, 2.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.666666667, 2, 1.666666667, 1.333333333, 
>   1, 1, 1, 1.166666667, 3.166666667, 3.333333333, 1.833333333, 
>   1, 2, 1, 2.166666667, 3, 1, 1.166666667, 1, NA, 1.5, 1.333333333, 
>   4, 3.5, 2.5, 2.333333333, 2.833333333, 2, 1.666666667, NA, 2.8, 
>   1.833333333, 2.666666667, 2.666666667, 2.666666667, 3, 3.666666667, 
>   3.833333333, 1.833333333, 1.166666667, 1.333333333, 1.5, 2.333333333, 
>   1, 1.833333333, 1.166666667, 3.333333333, 4.166666667, 2.166666667, 
>   2.6, 4.333333333, NA, 1.666666667, 1.666666667, 2.833333333, 
>   1.833333333, 2.5, 2.166666667, 4.166666667, 3.333333333, 3.833333333, 
>   2.5, 1.833333333, 1, 1, 1.166666667, 2.166666667, 2.666666667, 
>   1, 1, 1.5, 2, 1.5, 1.333333333, 1.833333333, 1.5, NA, NA, 3.333333333, 
>   1, 2.666666667, 2.666666667, 2.5, 1.166666667, 1.166666667, 1.333333333, 
>   1, 1.333333333, 2.333333333, 1.666666667, 1.5, 1.666666667, 1.333333333, 
>   1, 2, 1.833333333), Cognitiv_Anxiety = c(2.8, 1.6, 1.6, 1.4, 
>   2.6, 2.2, 3, 3.4, 3.6, 3.4, 1.2, 1.6, 1.8, NA, 2.2, 1.6, 3.2, 
>   2.4, 3, 2.2, 3.4, 2.8, 2.4, 2.8, 2.8, 2.25, 1.2, 1.666666667, 
>   2, 1.4, 2, 1.6, 1.75, 1.4, 4.2, 3.6, 3.333333333, 4.6, 3, 2.4, 
>   3.2, 4.4, 2, 1, 1.6, NA, 1.6, 1.2, 3.8, 4, 4.6, 4.8, 3.4, 2.6, 
>   4.2, NA, 4.2, 4.6, 3.8, 4.2, 1.4, 2.8, 3.4, 4.8, 3.6, 3.2, 3.4, 
>   3, 4.8, 4.2, 3.2, 3, 3, 3.6, 2.4, 3.2, 4.8, NA, 3.2, 3.25, 2, 
>   2.6, 2.6, 2.6, 5, 4.8, 4, 3.2, 2.4, 1.8, 1, 1, 3.4, 3.6, 1.4, 
>   1, 1.8, 2, 1, 1, 3.4, 2.8, NA, NA, 4.8, 1.6, 3.8, 3.6, 2.8, 1.8, 
>   2.4, 1.8, 3.4, 1, 2.4, 2.4, 2.6, 2.8, 1, 1, 2, 1.4), Confidence = c(4.2, 
>   4.6, 4.6, 5, 3.6, 4.4, 2.4, 2.8, 1.6, 1.4, 4.2, 3.6, 4, NA, 3.8, 
>   3.8, 4, 4.2, 3.2, 3.8, 3.8, 4, 2.4, 2.8, 2.8, 4, 4, 4, 3.8, 4.4, 
>   3.2, 4.4, 5, 4.8, 2.4, 2.6, 2.6, 3.2, 2.6, 2.8, 3.2, 2.8, 3.2, 
>   4.6, 3.2, NA, 5, 5, 2.6, 2.8, 1.6, 1, 5, 4, 2.6, NA, 2, 1.2, 
>   3, 1.6, 5, 4, 3.4, 2.8, 4.4, 3, 3.4, 4, 3.4, 3, 3.4, 3, 3.2, 
>   4.4, 3, 2.4, 1.4, NA, 4, 4.2, 4.4, 4.4, 3.2, 3.8, 1.2, 1, 1, 
>   2.8, 2.8, 3.4, 4.2, 5, 2, 1.8, 3.8, 5, 3.6, 3.4, 4.8, 4.2, 2.6, 
>   2.2, NA, NA, 1.2, 5, 2.8, 2.4, 3.6, 3.2, 4, 4.2, 4, 4, 3.2, 3.6, 
>   3.2, 3.6, 5, 5, 3.8, 3.4)), row.names = c(NA, -122L), class = c("tbl_df", 
>   "tbl", "data.frame"))

Comment: what is the error you are getting? Can you share your data using `dput(df)` ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your question is precise, but in order for us to understand and solve it, 
it is necessary that you provide some sample data. There are several ways to provide data, 
probably adding the output of `dput(<yourData>)` or `dput(head(<yourData>))` to your question is sufficient. 
Avoid adding code or alphanumeric output as images. Consider how to make a good example: 
  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example
and see how you can change your question accordingly.

Comment: Hello Mike, thnaks a lot for your help.